# What is the best way to have a function that returns by value heap allocate the return value?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14, new-operator

Let's say I have a simple function `returnString` that returns a string by value:

```
std::string returnString() {
   std::string s;
   // Use s in such a way to defeat return value mandatory copy-elision
   return s;
}
```

I have another function that wants to heap-allocate the result of this.  Easy enough.

```
void caller() {
   std::string* heap_allocated_string = new std::string(returnString());
}
```

Instead of `std::string` though, consider an arbitrary type `T`.  I believe that by the language rules, the following two statements are true.  Are they?

1. In C++14, I believe this is not ideal, since for some types if the move ctor is not free or not defined, we might be doing unnecessary work compared to just directly constructing on the heap.
2. In C++17, this triggers mandatory copy elision, so even if the type did not define a move constructor, no extra copy would be created, and the move constructor would not be called.

In general though, for a generic type, is there a better way to do this, without modifying the called function?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "better way". Your method is already bad, difficult to make it any worse. Just create automatic variable.

Comment: @Slava This is just an illustrative example.  There are plenty of cases where you'd actually want a return-by-value function to have a heap allocated result.

Comment: `returnString` returns a `std::string` a light wrapper around some heap allocated character array. `caller` assumes that the type returned by `returnString` should be allocated dynamically, but for a `std::string` thats rather pointless. Thats somewhat contradicting assumptions. I have a hard time to imagine a `T` for which you'd want both `returnString` and `caller` to be the way they are. At least in your example, using `std::string` does not make is simpler to understand the question, but rather more difficult.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number This is just an illustrative example.  Something more real-world would be a much more complex T that is factory-constructed by a 3rd party library that you want to store in an object pool you are managing yourself.

Comment: "Something more real-world would be a much more complex T that is factory-constructed" then that factory should return smart pointer.

Comment: @Slava You don't always have the option to modify other people's code.

Comment: If you need to return a heap allocated object and you cannot use any std container / string etc. - consider to return a `std::unique_ptr` (or `std::shaped_ptr` if the resource will be shared).

Comment: Then make a wrapper that will return smart pointer. But you probably should not use a library that returns a big complex object from factory by value.

Comment: @Slava Doesn't that just move this problem to the wrapper?

Comment: I do not understand what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: the `returnString` doesn't even fit guaranteed copy elision though.

Comment: now I see it again, you say both *"Use s in such a way to defeat return value mandatory copy-elision"* and *"In C++17, this triggers mandatory copy elision"* ?

Comment: I think the problem here is that you are trying to defining your code in terms of things that don't exist (like heap). Please try and describe the **ACTUAL** problem you are having so that we can look at in ways that you may not have actually considered that would solve the problem. Even after reading the comments it is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Which of the two fragments represents your code, and which is third-party code?

Comment: @MartinYork I can open a separate question with the actual real-world problem.  But I am interested in what the answer to the question would be as asked.

Comment: @Chuu: "*You don't always have the option to modify other people's code.*" If you can't modify the code generating the object... then there's nothing *you* can do. If internally creates the object as a stack variable and returns it, relying on NRVO, then that's what it will do. You can't make it do something else externally. Furthermore, I don't understand exactly what it is that you're trying to avoid. Why do you want to *prevent* optimizations?

Comment: Can I suggest changing `std::string` to a made-up `ReallyBigObject` to avoid triggering pedantic comments about how the contents of a std::string are already heap-allocated? Or perhaps an object that can't be moved.

Comment: @user253751: How do you return by value a variable in C++14 of a type that cannot be moved?

Comment: @user253751: "*Mandatory elision!*" That's not a thing in C++14.

Comment: @Slava: Now that we have “mandatory copy elision”, it’s much more reasonable to return by value: the client can still control the storage.  That said, a constructor is still superior for cases where you might want to use something like `std::optional`, since only `emplace` can avoid a move in that context.

Comment: @DavisHerring if that the case then OP should not move it to dynamically allocated storage at all, and there is no problem.

Comment: @Slava: Why mightn’t they want a `std::shared_ptr` for it or so?

Comment: @DavisHerring because by returning this way it would not have object slicing for example?

Comment: @Slava: Are you saying they might write `std::make_shared<Base>(Derived_by_value())`?  They can just omit the template argument to avoid that problem.

Answer (score 1):

> In C++14, I believe this is not ideal, since for some types if the move ctor is not free or not defined, we might be doing unnecessary work compared to just directly constructing on the heap.

Define "not ideal".

If the object has to be constructed via a factory function which returns by value, and you want to heap-allocate the object instead, and you have to do this "without modifying the called function," then that is as good as it's going to get.

Plus, you need not worry about the lack of copy/move in C++14. The reason being that it is (almost) impossible to return a non-copyable, non-moveable object by value in C++14. There is *technically* a way to do it (through the use of list-initialization syntax in the `return` statement), but if the function is written as you've stated it, then whatever type it returns *must* be copyable or moveable.

Furthermore, the `new` expression on your end doesn't even require named RVO; this part is just eliding a temporary, and there's no reason why a compiler wouldn't be able to optimize that move away.

So basically, there has to be a copy/move constructor for the function to compile, and any copy/move will be optimized away on your end for all practical purposes. So there's nothing to be concerned about.